# Create dataframe from text file based on certain criterias

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a text file that is around 3.3GB. I am only interested in 2 columns in this text file (out of 47). From these 2 columns, I only need rows where `col2=='text1'`. For example, consider my text file to have values such as:

text file:

```py
col1~col2~~~~~~~~~~~~
12345~text1~~~~~~~~~~~~
12365~text1~~~~~~~~~~~~
25674~text2~~~~~~~~~~~~
35458~text3~~~~~~~~~~~~
44985~text4~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I want to create a `df` where `col2=='text1'`. What I have done so far is tried to load the entire textfile into my `df` and then filter out the needed rows. However, since this is a large text file, creating a `df` takes more than 45 mins. I believe loading only the necessary rows (if possible) would be ideal as the `df` would be of considerably smaller size and I won't run into memory issues.

My code:

```py
df=pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',low_memory=False,sep='~',usecols=['col1','col2'],dtype={'col2':str})
df1=df[df['col2']=='text1']
```

In short, can I filter a column, based on a criteria, while loading the text file to dataframe so as to 1) Reduce time for loading and 2) Reduce the size of `df` on my memory.

Comment: Why `sep='~'` ? I do not see `~` in the sample

Comment: @harvpan my textfile is ~ delimited. I did not mention that, will edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I came up with a solution. Basically it has to do with loading the data in chunks, and filtering the chunks for `col2=='text1'`. This way, I only have a chunk loaded in memory each time and my final `df` will only have the data I need.

**Code:**

```py
final=pd.DataFrame()

df=pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',low_memory=False,sep='~',usecols=['col1','col2'],dtype={'col2':str},chunksize=100000)

for chunk in df:
    a=chunk[chunk['col2']=='text1']
    final=pd.concat([final,a],axis=0)
```

Better alternatives, if any, will be most welcome!

Comment: you could do futher processing in unix via cut and grep and pull the data back into pandas/python using the subprocess module. i dont have a sample file to work with though; it is just a suggestion. This post should explain more : https://op8867555.github.io/posts/2017-10-13-use-your-unix-toolbox-with-pandas.html

Comment: @sammywemmy I am working on a windows machine, but I believe chunksize does the same thing. It breaks the file into chunks and allows you to work one on it one chunk at a time. So we just have one chunk loaded into memory instead of the whole file.